# FollowHyperlink - VBA to Python

Tags: python

I have a desktop app which allows for URL scripting to automate downloads based on report type and date. I'm able to do so with the VBA code below which bypasses any browsers:

```
Sub Hyperlink()
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://www.example.com" 
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (URL)
End Sub
```

When I try to use any of the various Python examples it will open the browser to re-download the desktop app instead of initiating the automated download.

```
urllib.urlopen('http://example.com')
webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

Currently, I found a solution using win32com to create a temporary xlsm sheet to execute the VBA above.

```
import win32com.client

VBAscript = """
Sub Hyperlink()
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://www.example.com" 
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (URL)
End Sub
"""

xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')  # Initiate Excel
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()  # Open a workbook
mod = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  # Create a new Module
mod.CodeModule.AddFromString(VBAscript)  # Insert VBAscript as new Sub
xl.Run('Hyperlink')  # Run Hyperlink Macro
xl.DisplayAlerts = False  # Turn off DisplayAlerts (No Save Prompt)
xl.Quit()  # Close Excel
```

Besides the temporary xlsm sheet, are there any other ways to accomplish this using Python?